# IOS UISegmentedControl doesn't not display in ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm a beginner in IOS. I'm developping a Swift app and I am using a UISegmentedControl. It displays well in ios 11, but when I run my app on a IOS 10 device, the segmented control is not showing. Does anyone know why ?

Is the segmented control only available in IOS 11 ?

Here are the screenshots of my app (sorry I can't post images yet) :

IOS 11

[image: IOS 11 Version]

IOS10

[image: IOS10 Version]

Here is my SegmentedViewController.swift :

```
import UIKit
import MMDrawerController

class SegmentedViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView!

var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl!
var floorRequest:Int = 0
var segmentedControlIndex:Int = 0

lazy var travelViewController: TravelViewController = {
    var viewController = self.initTravelViewController()

    return viewController
}()

lazy var nearbyViewController: NearbyTableViewController = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NearbyTableViewController") as! NearbyTableViewController

    self.addViewControllerAsChildViewController(childViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()

var views: [UIView]!

let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


func initTravelViewController() -> TravelViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TravelViewController") as! TravelViewController

    viewController.floorRequest = floorRequest

    self.addViewControllerAsChildViewController(childViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    segmentedController = UISegmentedControl()
    navigationItem.titleView = segmentedController

    self.title = "TAB_BAR_MAP".localized()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "MENU_SECTION_TRAVEL".localized().uppercased()

    // Navigation Bar
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 18)!]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = appDelegate.colorAqaDark
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    if (self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count)! < 2 {
        let buttonLeft: UIButton = appDelegate.aqaBarButton(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconWhiteMenu"))
        buttonLeft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonLeft.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
        let buttonMenu = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonLeft)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(buttonMenu, animated: false);
    }

    setupView()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func toggleMenu() {
    appDelegate.mainContainer!.toggle(MMDrawerSide.left, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func setupView(){
    setupSegmentedControl()

    updateView()
}

private func updateView(){
    travelViewController.view.isHidden = !(segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    nearbyViewController.view.isHidden = (segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    segmentedControlIndex = segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex
}

private func setupSegmentedControl(){

    segmentedController.removeAllSegments()
    segmentedController.insertSegment(withTitle: "TAB_BAR_MAP".localized(), at: 0, animated: false)
    segmentedController.insertSegment(withTitle: "TAB_BAR_NEARBY".localized(), at: 1, animated: false)
    segmentedController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentedControlIndex
}

func selectionDidChange(sender: UISegmentedControl){
    updateView()
}

private func addViewControllerAsChildViewController(childViewController: UIViewController){
    addChildViewController(childViewController)
    view.addSubview(childViewController.view)

    childViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    childViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
}
```

Comment: You are not giving the segmented control any size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I didn't know that you have to set the size of it. it worked without setting it in ios 11.

Comment: In iOS 11 it is sized by autolayout. But not before.

Comment: Okay I understand now. I still have a lot to learn in IOS development. Thanks a lot you really saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not giving the segmented control any size. In iOS 11 the title view is sized internally by autolayout, but not in iOS 10 or before. So you end up with a segmented control of zero size.